# Как поставить картинку в качестве заднего фона для body?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, веб-программирование

Как мне поместить картинку на задний фон страницы, чтобы она заполнила экран полностью?
Этот код не помог:

```
body {
    background: url(ссылка на картинку);
}
```

Comment: Можно просто надо убрать внешние отступы у `body` с помощью `margin: 0`?

Comment: background-image

Answer (score 3):

Например так

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/1000/800) no-repeat center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

h1 {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<h1>Контент на странице</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

У каждого браузера есть свои дефолтные стили для тех или иных элементов.
Потому у вас по краям есть отступы

```
body {
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
   background: url(Ссылка на вашу картинку);
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Если вы не хоте что бы картинка повторялась по оси Y или оси Х, тогда нужно добавить ещё 
`background-repeat: no-repeat;`

простой пример:

```css
body  {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: url(https://ak5.picdn.net/shutterstock/videos/16547275/thumb/1.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  position: relative;
}

h1 {
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50% , -50%);
}
```

```html
ищ<body>
  <h1>EXEMPLE</h1>
</body>
```

[Полезная ссылка](https://webref.ru/css/background)